# Reload changed content created via ng-repeat without refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm currently trying to do the following, unfortunately without any success:

Basically, I have an array of objects, where for every object a button is created dynamically via the ng-repeat directive. When clicking a button, a new object is appended to the mentioned array (data will be sent to the server via api calls, the server will update the list internally and send the new array with the new object appended back to the view).

The same goes for deleting elements from that array.

Here's a little sample code of what I mean:

```
<span ng-repeat="x in allElements">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="elementButtons">{{x.id}}</button>
</span>
```

There will be as many buttons as elements in $scope.allElements.

Then there's also this button, which basically causes the array to be reset to 0 elements:

```
<button id="clearAllElements" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
data-toggle="button" ng-click="deleteAllElements()">Clear all</button>
```

The $scope.deleteAllElements() function calls the api to delete all elements from the server and fetches the new (empty) array from the server assigning it to $scope.allElements.

Now, how can I update the view without having to refresh the whole page such that only the created buttons are reloaded?

Thanks for any answers in advance,

a.j.stu

EDIT:

This is the function that is called when an element is to be added:

```
$scope.addElement = function(elementName) {
    if ($scope.checkElementName(elementName)) {
        var data = {"name": elementName.toUpperCase(),
                    "type": /*retrieve type of element from html element*/}

        $http.post("api/addElement/", JSON.stringify(data))
         .then(function(response) {
             $scope.allElements = response.data; //the api call adds the element in the backend and returns an array with all elements appended the new one. This SHOULD refresh the view of all element buttons, but doesn't.
         })
         .catch(function(response) {
             console.log("something went wrong adding element " + elementName); 
         })
         .then(function(response) {
           $('#newElementModal').modal('hide'); //#newElementModal is the modal that pops up when clicking a button to add a new element. here the name and type of the element are set and used in the api call above to add the element. Basically, when the modal hides, the view of all buttons should be refreshed.
         });
     } else {
        console.log("invalid identifier of element.");
}
```

As far as I've understood, the .then() calls are asynchronous. But, if there are only .then() calls following the api call, this should not be a problem, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If `deleteAllElements` deletes all elements, then no buttons will be displayed by your ng-repeat. Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is only an excerpt of functionalities. There is also an addElement button.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what your problem is. What doesn't work? What does clicking the addElement button do? Or what do you want it to do? If your controller functions do update the content of the $scope.allElements array, then you should not have to worry about refreshing the page. That is the purpose of angular data-binding.

Comment: When clicking the addElement button, I want the newly added element to be shown. The representation I gave was very simple, so let me go more into detail: Not all elements are the same. They have a different id and many other parameters that have to be set. When clicking the addElement button, a modal opens for configuration. The element with all set parameters will be added when a save button is clicked in the opened modal. the modal will close, but the element (in form of a button created via the ng-repeat directive) is not displayed.

Comment: Then you have to make it so the new element is added to $scope.allElements somehow. You should provide more code : the controllers related to this page and to the modal you use to create elements. Then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: "The $scope.deleteAllElements() function calls the api to delete all elements from the server and fetches the new (empty) array from the server assigning it to $scope.allElements." When adding an element, the principle is the same: the function $scope.addElement() is called invoking an api call, adding the element to the list stored in the model, where an updated representation of this list is assigned to allElements, which is also received via an api call. The problem is not that the element is not added to the list, the problem is that I don't know how to refresh the view.

Comment: You don't have to refresh the view. If you populate $scope.allElements with new data, your view will update itself. As long as the modal and the view use the same $scope.allElements array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have to worry about resfreshing the page. If your view is connected to the controller whose $scope is updated by the API calls adding and deleting elements, your view will adapt and display the new content.

For what it's worth, here's a snippet showing how it could work. Minus the API calls that add / delete data.

```js
angular.module('dummyApp', [])
  .controller('DummyController', function($scope) {

    $scope.allElements = [
    { id : 1, name : "Joe"},
    { id : 2, name : "John"},
    { id : 3, name : "Jane"},
    { id : 4, name : "Alice"},
    ];
    
    $scope.deleteAllElements = function () {
      // deleting elements empties the $scope.allElements array
      $scope.allElements.length = 0;
    };
    
    $scope.addElement = function () {
      var element = {
        id : generateId(),
        name : 'whatever'
      }
      // new elements are pushed into the $scope.allElements array
      $scope.allElements.push(element);
    };
    
    function generateId() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="dummyApp" ng-controller="DummyController">
  <span ng-repeat="x in allElements">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="elementButtons">{{x.id}}</button>
  </span>
<br/><br/>
<button id="clearAllElements" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
data-toggle="button" ng-click="deleteAllElements()">Clear all</button>
<button id="clearAllElements" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
data-toggle="button" ng-click="addElement()">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I see your point, seems like there must be some problem with the order of my function calls. I will update the question with a method that calls the functions in the same order as I do.

Answer (score 0):

use trackby x.id to update the view without refreshing the whole page

Answer (score 0):

Just assign new response data from your server to $scope.allElements and it will be refreshed  without reloading page.